# Registering for the Belgian elections 2019

Tags: elections, belgian-citizens

A Belgian *uitgeschreven* (means having unregistered residency) and living abroad in the East. Is this person obliged to **register** to vote, and do they have to vote, because they received an email from the consulate with registration forms to complete?

Answer (score 1):

A little late but the details outlined in this article are still relevant. Quoted from [Stemrecht en stemplicht bij verkiezingen](https://www.vlaanderen.be/stemrecht-en-stemplicht-bij-verkiezingen):

> Voor de federale, regionale en Europese verkiezingen van zondag 26 mei 2019 moet u gaan stemmen in de gemeente waar u ten laatste op vrijdag 1 maart 2019 bent gedomicilieerd (ook al bent u daarna naar een andere gemeente verhuisd).
>
> Op voorwaarde dat u een geldige reden hebt om zelf niet aan de verkiezingen deel te nemen, kunt u een volmacht aan een andere kiezer geven. Ook als u zich op de dag van de verkiezingen in het buitenland bevindt kunt u een volmacht geven.
>
> Als u als Belg in het buitenland woont, geldt de stemplicht niet automatisch. U moet eerst een aanvraag indienen tot deelname aan de federale en de Europese verkiezingen((opent in nieuw venster)) (als u geen domicilie in België hebt, kunt u sowieso niet deelnemen aan de lokale, provinciale en regionale verkiezingen).

It appears that yes if before the 1st of March 2019 you had residency within Belgium you would need to vote or pass your vote to a third person to vote on your behalf. There are more legal steps outlined in that article and relevant links.

See also [Hoe inschrijven?](https://verkiezingen.fgov.be/kiezers/hoe-inschrijven) detailing steps to take to vote but in your case this is not compulsory.